# how can I build a query that retrieve lesson modules strictly that matches to the lesson?

Tags: python, django

how can I retrieve the lesson modules by its parent lesson strictly? e.g if I change to the next lesson where at the same contains a lessonmodule `/lesson1/task1` this one shouldn't display since it doesn't belong to lesson2? how can I fix this by only retrieve slugs, content by the lesson attach to?

views

```
class LessonDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = "/account/login/"

    def get(self, request, course_slug, lesson_slug, *args, **kwargs):
        lesson = get_object_or_404(Lesson.objects.select_related('course'), slug=lesson_slug, course__slug=course_slug)
        lessonmodule = get_object_or_404(LessonModule.objects.select_related('lesson'), slug='hello_world')
        context = {
            'object': lessonmodule,
            'previous_lesson': lesson.get_previous_by_created_at,
            'next_lesson': lesson.get_next_by_created_at,
        }
        return render(request, "courses/lesson_detail.html", context)
```

models

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=25,unique=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lesson-detail',
                       kwargs={
                           'course_slug': self.course.slug,
                           'lesson_slug': self.slug
                       })


class LessonModule(models.Model):
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
  content = models.TextField()
  lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  allowed_memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Membership)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.slug
```

template

```
{% block content %}
    <div class='container'>
        <h1>Lesson Detail View</h1>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-6'>
                {% if object is not None %}
                <h3>{{ object.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ object.course.description }}</p>
                {{object}}
                {% if previous_lesson %}
                <a href="{{ previous_lesson.get_absolute_url }}">Back</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if next_lesson %}
                <a href="{{ next_lesson.get_absolute_url }}">Next</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% else %}
                <h3>Upgrade membership</h3>
                <p>To view this course you'll need to upgrade your membership</p>
                <br>
                <hr>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see here, you can have multiple `LessonModule` for a single `Lesson` due to one-to-many relation between `Lesson` and `LessonModule`(ForeignKey relation basically). You can fetch all the `LessonModules` like this(using [reverse query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager)):

```
# view
def get(self, request, course_slug, lesson_slug, *args, **kwargs):
    lesson = get_object_or_404(Lesson.objects.select_related('course').prefetch_related('lessonmodule_set'), slug=lesson_slug, course__slug=course_slug)
    context = {
        'object': lesson,
        'previous_lesson': lesson.get_previous_by_created_at,
        'next_lesson': lesson.get_next_by_created_at,
    }
    return render(request, "courses/lesson_detail.html", context)


# template
{% for lesson_module in object.lessonmodule_set.all %}
   {{ lesson_module.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am just sending the `Lesson` object to template, and using reverse query in template to get `LessonModule` objects.